# Date based on day of 365 Day Year

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, date

I have a date in the format [last two year][day of 365]. Using either SQL or excel functions, I need to determine the date this pertains to. The year is always the last two of the 2000s. There are no dates from before 2007. Is there a way to easily do this? I'm using this for a quick check, and am trying to avoid a large coding time for this.

Comment: Create a Date starting at January 1, 20xx then add your days to it. (where xx is obviously the last two of the year)

Comment: can you give a nummeric representation?  Is it 07001 through 07365 or something else?

Comment: StuartAinsworth: The start date would be 07001 the end date would be 12365

Comment: NominSim: Could you give me a code example in either SQL or Excel please?

Comment: Looking for a Feb. 29th bug? 2008 was a leap year.

Comment: @fluffy Seems to have got it stevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, the date-handling functions seem to vary widely by SQL vendor, and there don't seem to be any good standard ways of handling date offsets.  However, if you were a bit more specific about the specific SQL server you're using, someone might be able to provide an answer that applies.

In Excel, you can build a date for the first day of the year (e.g. 2008-01-01) and then add the number of days numerically, subtracting 1 so that the first day is still 2008-01-01; the resulting value, when formatted as a date, should be the precise date value.  For example, `=DATE(2008,1,1)-1+320` returns a date of 11/15/08 (at least in LibreOffice Calc).

Comment: `=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE("20",LEFT(A1,2),"-01-01"))-1+INT(RIGHT(A1,3))` works in Excel 2010, where the five digits (stored as text) are in `A1`.

Comment: `=DATE(LEFT(A1,IF(LEN(A1)=5,2,1))+100,1,RIGHT(A1,3))` works in Excel and does not require the 5 digits (with a leading 0) to be stored as text. Slight variance on barry houdini's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula in Excel where your data is in A1

`=DATE(LEFT(A1,2)+100,1,RIGHT(A1,3))`